# Fluxx: Hand limit zero + trade hands

Tags: fluxx

A rule was in place that said the hand limit was zero. It states that if it isn't your turn you should have zero cards.

Other rules in play were draw three, play one.

While it was 'Person A's turn he played trade hands card. That means he gave the cards to 'Person B'. There were no modifiers at the time to the standard rule 'play one card'.

So my question is does the trade hands card need to fully resolve - meaning does person B have to discard the cards before the start of his turn. Or does the end of 'Person A's turn ended the moment he played the trade hands card, and person B gets to keep he cards at the start of his next turn.

Edit: I am hoping someone can cite an actual rule why Joe W is correct. My opponent isn't buying the logic and insists his turn is over the moment he traded the cards, so therefore I should keep the cards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What will happen is Player A will pass his hand to Player B (should be 2 cards since Player A would have had 0 cards to start the turn, drew 3 and played 1) and since no other player can have cards due to the hand limit Player A gets no cards in return. Once the cards reach Player B's hand the hand limit will kick into action and force him to discard both cards and  return to 0 cards in his hand. At this point the trade action will be fully completed and  Player B will be able to start his turn by drawing 3 cards and playing one of the 3 cards now in hand.

There is also a rule that lets you take a free action of taking the top card of the deck and playing it. This action does not have to happen before you take your last action and is allowed to happen after you have taken your last action and before the next players turn ends. This should make it more clear that the player in this case has to discard the 2 cards.

Comment: I am player B and I agree with this assessment. =P. Funny part is player A is advocating that I keep the cards, which would make me win the game. I think he is wrong and I didn't win. Sigh.

Comment: What you need to consider is that the hand limit rule (when it is not your turn) happens as an atomic action in regards to you getting more cards. What that means is that as soon as you get two cards from the other player you would need to discard enough to meet this limit. Even though the other player has no cards in his hand need to follow any end of turn rules that are now in effect. An example could be having to discard keepers because a keeper limit is in play. Only after all of his end of turn actions are done does play switch to the next player and remove the hand limit from them.

Comment: As I stated. I agree with this completely. Despite the fact that we think alike about this, there is nothing specific in the rules to prove that this is the way the game is meant to be played, correct? My opponent is refusing our logic, simply saying the turn ended the moment he handed me the cards to trade hands. Therefore I can keep the cards. I say I had to discard them as I received them when it wasn't my turn. (Incidentally, if I had been able to keep the cards, I would win. I just don't think I did because I had to discard them). If I can't cite rules, he won't buy it.

Comment: Found something in the FAQs that inadvertently describes turn endings. They mention you have the opportunity to take your free action up until the next person starts taking their turn. This implies your turn certainly isn't over simply by carrying out the action on the card you are allowed to play. I suppose I could also argue that the action card itself says 'do whatever it says, then place it on the discard pile'. This in itself is implying it isn't complete until you do what it says and discard it. He seems to be accepting the FAQ inference either way. Thanks.

Comment: @JHubbard80 I have added that to my answer, I knew about that rule card and should have put it in my answer to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

While player B is holding cards, there is a violation of the hand limit rule, and that violation has to be resolved before the game can continue. This also means the trade hands card cannot fully resolve until player B has discarded his hand.